# Comparing two char pointers, but if pointer two has only 1 letter it doesn't work

Tags: c++

```
int vorkommen(const char* s, const char* m) {

    int lengthS = 0;
    int lengthM = 0;

    while (s[lengthS] != '\0') {
        lengthS++;
    }

    while (m[lengthM] != '\0') {
        lengthM++;
    }

    char textS[lengthS - 1];
    char textM[lengthM - 1];



    for(int i = 0; i < lengthS; i++) {
        textS[i] = s[0];
        s++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthM; i++) {
        textM[i] = m[0];
        m++;
    }

    int match = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= lengthM; j++) {

            if(j == lengthM) {
                match++;
            } else if(textS[i + j] != textM[j]) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    return match;

}

void Aufgabe_7() {

    char first[256];
    char second[256];

    cin.getline(first, sizeof(first));
    cin.getline(second, sizeof(second));

    int test = vorkommen(first, second);

    cout << test;

}


int main() {
    Aufgabe_7();
    return 0;
}
```

You see here a program which only task is it, to read in two texts and compare how often the text of the second char pointer is contained in the first char pointer.

For that I wrote this little program, it works and all but if the second char pointer contains only 1 letter the output of textS[0] is always equals to textM[0].

Comment: `char textS[lengthS - 1];` is not valid standard C++. C++ array sizes *must* be compile time constants. VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are a compiler extension. If you need a dynamically sized array in C++, then that is spelled [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). And for statically sized arrays, consider `std::array` - forget that C-style arrays exist in the language and never use them again.

Comment: This results in what I got teached and in our solutions we are not allowed to use anything we didn't had in class before. This solution worked for me quite well until this point. But thanks anyways for the comment!

Comment: Just because someone teaches you something does not mean that it is good. Using C-style arrays in modern C++ is a big red flag and using compiler extensions rather than standard compliant C++ is a huge one. (IMHO)

Comment: Well, sure, the last time he has updated his knowledge about this stuff is probably years ago, but anyways I'm not allowed to use std:array or std::vector in this answer.

Comment: @Marakaner You don't need to copy the input strings into local arrays just to compare the strings. Your `vorkommen()` function can be implemented MUCH more simply by just using the original pointers as-is.

Comment: I don't want to compare the two strings if they are equals, I want to scan the first input how often it contains the pattern of the second input. I hope I got your comment right there.

Comment: If you are comparing *pointers*, their target sizes don't matter.  A pointer could be pointing to one character or 10000 characters.  The pointers point to the first item; so essentially you are comparing the starting locations of these items; not their content.